# How to back up photos without USB in Windows Phone 7.*? No Zune Sync

Tags: lumia, 7.8, backup

I have a Nokia Lumia 710 (Windows Phone 7.8) here, and the USB port has been damaged.  It still charges, but USB syncing is no longer possible.  The owner of the phone wants their photos backed up, but didn't have Upload to OneDrive enabled when they took them, and it doesn't retroactively upload them.  Manually going through the process of uploading a photo a good 600 times would take days.  Bluetooth Share only allows for single file transfers at a time.  No memory card slot.

Does anybody have any idea how to bulk backup the photographs without USB?  Wireless sync requires that I sync the phone at least once with a cable which is no longer possible.

Comment: Does this APP still work ? I'm looking at the 2 mappings but they're not "sending"

Answer (score 6):

After some searching, I found an app called [Photo2Cloud for Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/photo2cloud/80d61904-b63d-42ef-a39f-dd6b41c16c83). The app is free and supports batch upload. I was able to...

1. Add my OneDrive account to the app
2. Select any of the Albums (Camera Roll, etc)
3. Select the destination folder on OneDrive.
4. Run a sync between the two folders which uploaded all the files to OneDrive.

So, as long as you have a decent internet connection, uploading 600+ photos shouldn't take days :)